# trouble with layer-list in xml drawable?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, xml-drawable

I am trying to design a layout using xml. it's a chat bubble layout. I just need a shape to be place after a shape. basically i am using 2 rectangles 1 rectangle rotated by 45 degree. i need tilted rectangle to placed after a normal rectangle.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="-45"
            android:pivotX="0%"
            android:pivotY="0%"
            android:toDegrees="0" >
            <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
                <solid android:color="@color/chat_incoming_color" />
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>
    <item android:left="16dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid android:color="@color/chat_incoming_color" />
            <corners android:radius="4dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fLdi4.jpg
image is shown in the link in that image first part is ok but second layout's background should be made accordingly..

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "after"? "side-by-side"? or "below y-wise"? or "below z-wise"?

Comment: i have to place normal rectangle first followed by tilted rectangle

Comment: You still haven't answered my question. What exactly does "followed" mean?

Comment: i mean side by side

Comment: simply use 9-patch drawable for such cases

Comment: solved that issue by using 9 patch image

Answer (score 0):

Try this I hope it will help you to understand your problem.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

        <item>
            <rotate android:fromDegrees="45"
                    android:pivotX="-35%"
                    android:pivotY="91%"
                    android:toDegrees="0">
                <shape>
                    <solid android:color="@android:color/darker_gray"/>
                </shape>
            </rotate>
        </item>
        <item android:left="16dp">
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <solid android:color="@android:color/darker_gray"/>
                <corners android:radius="4dp"/>
            </shape>
        </item>

    </layer-list>
```

Comment: Ok.. may i know exactly what you want?

Comment: I provided link to the image. in that layout for first part is ok but i cannot modify 2 part according to need.

Comment: Try this link https://www.androidtutorialpoint.com/basics/android-chat-bubble-layout-9-patch-image-using-listview/